# Getting the XML editor and the Android Common XML editor in Eclipse in the same window

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I was trying to customize Eclipse for Android development and ran into this "problem".

When you open a XML file with the Common Android XML Editor you get 2 tabs at the bottom, Graphical Layout and the regular text source.

When you open a XML file with the XML Editor you get 2 tabs, Design and Source. Design being the Node view which I find useful sometimes.

Is it possible to somehow get the Design tab in the Common Android XML Editor window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user you cannot take a page from one editor and use it in another. Depending on the implementation details of the editor pages, a plugin developer could create a new editor implementation that re-uses existing pages.

Comment: Looks like this is the perfect opportunity to learn to create Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can't reuse tabs from one editor in another (at least, not without programming, as Konstantin pointed out), you can open the same file in two different editors at the same time and have them side-by-side. Open the file with the default editor, then right-click on the file, choose *Open With*, and select the alternate editor. With both editor open, you can drag the tab of one of them and move it so the two are side-by-side.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of what I was trying to avoid doing.